# MySQL Join Update

Tags: mysql, sql, join

A (supposedly) simple update has turned out to be not so simple. No matter which syntax I try from other answered questions, I get the same response from MySQL:

0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 124  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

Try 1:

```
UPDATE news_content, news_map
SET news_content.active='no'
WHERE news_content.rowID = news_map.newsID
AND news_map.catID = 170;
```

Try 2:

```
UPDATE  news_content
LEFT JOIN
    news_map
ON      news_map.newsID = news_content.rowID
SET     news_content.active = 'no'
WHERE   news_map.catID = 170;
```

Try 3:

```
UPDATE 
news_content nc JOIN
news_map nm 
  ON nm.newsID = nc.rowID 
  AND nm.catID = 170
SET nc.active = 'no';
```

What do you think will work?

Comment: all of the syntax should worked fine. can you give sample records? check the values again.

Comment: What does `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM news_content nc JOIN
news_map nm ON nm.newsID = nc.rowID WHERE nm.catID = 170
AND (nc.active <> 'no' OR nc.active IS NULL);` return?

Comment: @ypercube, it returns 19

Comment: Is there any Update trigger on the `news_content` table?

Answer (score 1):

Might be a silly question but does news_content.active already equal 'no'?

Comment: There are 105 'no' and 19 'yes'.

Comment: The most probable cause. The rows to be updated have already `active = 'no'` (and MySQL in contrast with other DBMS, does check.)

Answer (score 0):

Are there any rows returned by this:

```
select *
from news_content
LEFT JOIN
    news_map
ON      news_map.newsID = news_content.rowID
WHERE   news_map.catID = 170
```

Comment: i think this should be a comment `:)`

Comment: @JW. yep) but how to add comments instead of answers?

Comment: @walkerspace, what about:     

    UPDATE  news_content
    SET     active = 'no'
    from news_content
    LEFT JOIN
        news_map
    ON      news_map.newsID = news_content.rowID
    WHERE   news_map.catID = 170;

Comment: @shibormot, MySQL gives a syntax error with the FROM part of that query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE news_content
SET active='no'
WHERE rowID IN (SELECT m.newsID FROM news_map m WHERE m.catID = 170);
```

I prefer to use sub-query instead of JOIN on UPDATE, in general, as it is a more standard way.